# Splitting string 2 times with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, split

I am trying to break up this string by first splitting it into sections divided by ';'.  Then I want to split those sections divided by ','.  It is not working though and I am about to break my computer.  Could someone please help me figure this out.

You can play around with my jsfiddle if you want... http://jsfiddle.net/ChaZz/

```
var myString = "Call 1-877-968-7762 to initiate your leave.,-30,0,through;You are eligible to receive 50% pay.,0,365,through;Your leave will be unpaid.,365,0,After;";

var mySplitResult = myString.split(";");

for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length -1; i++){
    var mySplitResult2 = i.split(",");
    for(z = 0; z < mySplitResult2.length -1; i++) {
    //document.write("<br /> Element " + i + " = " + mySplitResult[i]);
        document.write("<br/>Element" + z + " = " + mySplitResult[z]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(z = 0; z < mySplitResult2.length -1; i++) {` you probably meant `z++` there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i` is a number, as that's how you defined it.

To split the string, you need to access the `i` member of the Array.

```
var mySplitResult2 = mySplitResult[i].split(",");
```

Comment: @StackOver: `mySplitResult` is an Array, so you just use typical array member access `mySplitResult[i].split(",")`

Comment: Do you know why it's doing this?

Answer (score 2):

If I may, if you have to split with character `a` then character `b`, the simplest would be :
`string.split('a').join('b').split('b')`